# undefined error while inserting data into table

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to insert into db and display the data in listview. but i am getting this error.

```
  05-14 19:43:56.336: E/Web Console(1480): TypeError: Result of expression 'c[0]' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:2
```

this is what i am trying to do

```
function listdata(tx, resultset) {
    div = null;
    list = null;
    var row = null;
    list = $("<ul>").attr({
        'data-role' : 'listview',
        'data-inset' : 'false',
        'id' : 'mylist'
    });
    count = resultset.rows.length;

    $(list).remove();

    $.each(resultset.rows, function(index) {
        row = resultset.rows.item(index);
        var li = '<li><a href="#">' + row['Date'] + '</a></li>';
        list.append(li);
    });
    div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsible="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"><h3>' + row['name'] + '<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" data-iconpos="right">' + count + '</span></h3></div>';

    $(list).appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('[data-role="content"]').end().trigger("create");
    $('div[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible({
        theme : 'a',
        refresh : true
    }); 
    $('[data-role="listview"]').listview().listview('refresh'); 
}
```

Can i know why is this error I am getting?

Thanks:)

Comment: You didn't define `list` as `var list`, so it's going to be undefined inside your `$.each()` call...

Comment: i have defined var list as global varible

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `$(list).remove()` which will remove the whole `<ul>` from the Dom. You need to use `list.html("");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain bit what you are asking me to do.. because i am new to it.